# How can I make a figure that includes sub-figures at multiple-rows but different number of columns?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have 5 sub-figures in two rows. Two sub-figures are in first row and three sub-figures are  in second row. So, the organization should seem as shown in the picture. Due to non-symmetry between two rows, I could not make it. Could you please help me ? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Instead of a tabular with two rows use two tabulars with one row each, the first with two columns and the second with three.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks. I applied this easy solution. In order to centralize the first row, I also used \begin{center} \end{center}.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility using [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.333\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.333\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}\par\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.333\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.333\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.333\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{the general caption}
\label{fig:fivesubfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```